# How to run driftnet on Ubuntu Properly

Tags: 12.04

I hope this is the right place to put this question. So I'm trying to do arp cache poisoning. I've using my phone as a local network. I was successfully able to listen into the packets using wireshark. But I'm having troubles using driftnet. Zero pictures are being saved shown or saved. I also tried to test this out on another network at starbucks but was also unsuccessful.

My current setup - I have 2 Vmware running, both with ubuntu loaded.

1 machine is for the man in the middle, the other virtual machine is the one being watched.

I ran ettercap -G, selectecd the interface, searched for the host, sniffed and applied arp poisoning. I then went to turn on `driftnet -i eth0` but it says "The connection is closed" and nothing happens when machine 2 browses the internet.

If I can get some tips it'd be greatly appreciated.